# Fill content depending on who the email is sent to

Tags: vba, email, outlook

When I receive an email request to get something completed, I need to forward an email to email@kace to create a ticket.

When I have that specific email address as the recipient, I'd like the following 4 lines of text to appear in the body of the forwarded message (and remove my signature if possible too):

@submitter=

@owner=

@title=

@category=

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is certainly possible.  Handle the Inspectors.NewInspector event and detect when a new MailItem object is being created (check for MailItem.Sent = False).  You can then inspect the MailItem.Recipients collection to look for a specific user (or MailItem.SenderEmailAddress or .SenderName).  Then just modify the MailItem.Body or MailItem.HTMLBody content to insert what you need.

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate on this more? I know nothing about Outlook or Visual Basic. Would you be able to create a step by step process of how this would be completed?

Comment: Do you know how to code at all?  I can certainly answer specific questions, but I can't really teach you how to program from scratch - that's not the intent of this site.  There are some great walkthroughs and code samples on MSDN that can get you started: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ff868025.aspx.

Comment: I know how to code for the web but not Visual Basic or Outlook. I was hoping there was an easy copy/paste method with the variables that I gave to get it done. But if there's way more to it, I guess I'll have to look into this further.

Comment: It shouldn't be too difficult - check out the MSDN reference to get started. The key is you need a module level variable for an Outlook.Inspectors object set with the "WithEvents" keyword so you can expose the events that you can trap. Start with the Application.StartUp event in the editor and set your Inspector reference there.  Then in the NewInspector event work with the MailItem object via the Inspector object passed in the parameter and get it from Inspector.CurrentItem.  Then set MailItem.Body or .HTMLBody.